# Socket throughput on localhost?

Tags: c++, sockets

I've got an app that's using sockets to push data, and I'm currently testing it on my localhost (so that the sender and receiver are on the same computer).  I'm seeing between 36 and 66MB/s of throughput, which seems somewhat slow to me.  What are normal throughput ranges for binary data on a local socket connection?